# Is salt formation catabolic or anabolic?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, thermodynamics, salt

In class we learned that catabolic reactions are exergonic. I later checked that the free energy change of salt formation, $$\ce{2Na + Cl2 -> NaCl}$$ has a negative $\Delta G$. What explains this? Am I even asking the right question?

Comment: The terms catabolic/anabolic reactions apply rather in context of  breaking/building larger molecules in context of metabolism. They are not used in context of small inorganic molecular entities.

Comment: You would be asking the right question if an organism could metabolize sodium using chlorine as an oxidizer.

Answer (score 1):

The heat of formation of $\ce{NaCl}$ is $\Delta$$\ce{H}$ = - $411$ kJ/mol. This is much. In order for the synthesis of $\ce{NaCl}$ to be spontaneous, the change of free enthalpy must be known and must be < $0$. As this synthesis implies the disparition of a gaz ($\ce{Cl2}$), the reaction is accompanied by a decrease of entropy : $\Delta\ce{S}$ < $0$. The Tables give : $\Delta$$\ce{S}$ = - $180$ J/mol. So $\ce{T$\Delta$S}$ is - $53$ kJ/mol at $25$°C. As a consequence $\Delta$$\ce{G}$ = $\Delta$$\ce{H}$ - $\ce{T}\Delta\ce{S}$ = - $411$ kJ/mol + $53$ kJ/mol = - $358$ kJ/mol which is also negative. So the reaction is spontaneous, as expected.  This is also what you have found. As you are looking for an explanation for the origin of this negative sign, it is due to the high negative value of $\Delta$$\ce{H}$. The negative value of $\Delta$$\ce{S}$ (and of $\ce{T}$$\Delta\ce{S}$) may be important ; it is not sufficient to reverse the sign of $\Delta$H when deriving the value of $\Delta\ce{G}$, through $\Delta\ce{G}$ = $\Delta\ce{H}$ - $\ce{T}\Delta\ce{S}$

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Indeed this is above the scope of what we discussed in class. So would you say the formation of NaCl is anabolic since it's combining into a larger molecule? Or do we only use the words anabolism and catabolism in reference to metabolic molecules like glucose? Thank you.

Comment: The terms "anabolic" and "catabolic" are used in biology. In chemistry we prefer to speak of broken or made up bonds. In the synthesis of NaCl, one bond is broken ($\ce{Cl2}$) which does not cost much energy. But  the bond in $\ce{NaCl}$ is much stronger, so strong that the synthesis of $\ce{NaCl}$ is rather strongly exothermic. It is so exothermic, that the energy for breaking $\ce{Cl2}$ is so small that it can nearly be neglected.

Comment: @Maurice Please do not use `\ce{…}` for the symbols of physical quantities. This is wrong not only semantically, but also from the formatting standpoint since they are variables and should not be upright. Also, do not invoke several math modes in a row, use *one* mode per expression: you pollute the code with dollar signs and make spacing all wrong. Since you are loading `mhchem` by using `\ce{…}`, consider formatting units properly with `\pu{…}`, too.